# tc match IPv4 fragment offset

Tags: linux, networking, tc

What is the correct Syntax for matching Fragments that have and Offset > 0 in tc?

I have tried:

```
... u32 match u8 255 ff at 7 flowid 2:1
```

But to no avail

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IPv4 Header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1) [Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) (don't be fooled by the numbering when pondering bits later), you must compare the 13 lower bits of the combined two bytes at offset 6 and 7.

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |         Identification        |Flags|      Fragment Offset    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |  Time to Live |    Protocol   |         Header Checksum       |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                       Source Address                          |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Destination Address                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

So it can't be matched with *u8* but requires for example *u16*. Also, [*tc u32*](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-u32.8) appears to lack a *not* logical operator, thus it can only reliably match packets *without* fragment offset (or packets with no offset but the MF set etc.) in one rule. There's even abbreviations for this, if you also want to also include the MF flag in the check:

```
... u32 match ip nofrag flowid 2:1 # would match the opposite of what's wanted
```

without MF flag:

```
... protocol ip u32 match u16 0 0x1fff flowid 2:1
```

So you can either use two filters to invert the logic, the first filter to bypass the second (you can complement the *action* with an other *flowid* if needed):

```
... prio 1 protocol ip u32 match u16 0 0x1fff action pass
... prio 2 protocol ip matchall flowid 2:1
```

or you can completely change the filter module and use [*tc basic*](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-basic.8)'s [*ematch*](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-ematch.8) features which include logical operators like *not*, thus achieving goal in one filter:

```
... protocol ip basic match 'not cmp(u16 at 6 layer network mask 0x1fff eq 0)' flowid 2:1
```